# How do I include the object files for openssl/md5 library?

Tags: c, unix

I have included the openssl/md5.h in my source.

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
```

This is my (part of) my code:

```
char *pf_generate_pfdhr_string(int firstfree, int numpages)
{
    const int md5_digest_len = 16;
    char hash[md5_digest_len];

    MD5_CTX md5_ctx;
    MD5_Init(&md5_ctx);
    int hdr_arr[2] = {firstfree, numpages};
    MD5_Update(&md5_ctx, hdr_arr, 2*sizeof(int));
    MD5_Final(hash, &md5_ctx);

    return hash;
}
```

And this is my output

```
ranlib build/libpf.a
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic     tests/pf_tests.c build/libpf.a   -o tests/pf_tests
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MD5_Final", referenced from:
      _pf_generate_pfdhr_string in libpf.a(pf.o)
  "_MD5_Init", referenced from:
      _pf_generate_pfdhr_string in libpf.a(pf.o)
  "_MD5_Update", referenced from:
      _pf_generate_pfdhr_string in libpf.a(pf.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [tests/pf_tests] Error 1
```

I have included the header file so the compiler knows the function exists. However, it seems unable to find the object files for the md5 library. How can I include it in my build?

If I am using Make, what is the best way to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the documentation for your platform. It may be `-lcrypto -lssl`. It may not be. If your platform supports `pkg-config`, use `pkg-config --libs openssl`.

Comment: -lcrypto compiler flag onto clang worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: cmake: target_link_libraries(ProjectName crypto)